# Why browser dosen't support some tags

Tags: javascript, tags

Do you know why some tags are supported by some browsers while other browsers can't support them, my mentor says there is a point behind that, please lemme know the answer :-)

Comment: what do you mean by tags? html tags, like `<a></a>`?

Comment: The answer is Microsoft, Mozilla, Google and Apple

Comment: yes HTML tags @PatrickEvans